# Deploying an executable with a configuration file

Tags: c++, c, linux, gnu-make

I'm new to deploying programs written in C/C++ on Linux and I'm wondering what you'd do in this situation.

I have a binary file (compiled with GNU Make) that needs to read a config file (such as `myprogram.conf`). But when I write a Makefile to deploy this file to `/usr/bin/`, where should the config file go? And how does the executable know where it is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have endless options, but the best way depends on a couple of things. First, is it a user-specific configuration file, or is it global to all users?

If it's user specific, you could, for example, keep it in ~/.myprogram/config.file and have the program check there. As a service to your users, it's up to you to decide what to do if it's not found -- perhaps copy a default config there from somewhere else, or generate a default, or use hard-coded default options, or display a configuration wizard, or just fail. That's entirely up to you.

If it's global, the traditional place to put it on Linux is in /etc, e.g. /etc/config.file or /etc/myprogram/config.file. See [Linux File System Structure](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-file-system-structure/). You will generally always have a /etc on Linux. Handling a situation where the file does not exist is the same as above - there's no "right" way to handle that, it's based purely on how convenient you want to make it for a user.

What I usually do for global config files is put them in /etc/wherever on install, have the program default to loading the config file from /etc/wherever, but also give a command line option to override the configuration file (especially useful for testing or other situations).

What I usually do to handle missing config files depends entirely on the application. I'll generally either have hard-coded defaults (if that's appropriate) or simply fail and direct the user to some documentation describing a config file (which I find adequate in situations where my installer installs a config file).

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for "command line option" - something I missed in my answer.

Comment: Actually don't forget environment variables.  For testing, sample installation, relocatable installation, etc. you can't beat environment variables.  To support reproducible builds we have a Git repo containing lots of 3rdparty software we need, and because any given user might create their local git workspace anywhere, we need stuff to be relocatable.  If the software supports environment variables to specify where configuration belongs, you can write a small shell script wrapper around it that sets the environment variable appropriately then calls the real application.

Answer (score 2):

It kind of depends on what the configuration parameters are, and whether they are "per system" or "per user" or "per group" or ...

System configurations typically live somewhere in `/etc/...`. In the same directory that the program lives is a very good place too.

User confgiurations, in the home directory of the user.

Group configurations are the trickiest, as you'll probably need to come up with a scheme where there is a configuration file per "group". `/etc/myprog/groups/<groupname>/config` or something similar would work.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, the usual location for configuration files is '/etc', so it is acceptable to deploy a configuration file like `/etc/myprog.conf`. That requires root privileges however. Other good options include putting a configuration file in the user's home directory, making it something like `~/.myprog.conf` or `~/.myprog/.conf` to use a folder where you can have several config files, a cache or something else that you want.

As for how the executable knows where the file is, one solution is to look for the file in several common locations. For example, if you decided to place your config in the user's home directory, look for it there first, if not found, look under `/etc`. And allow a special command line argument that would let a different config file to be loaded. So, say, an invocation of `myprog` can check for a config file in the home folder, but `myprog -c /some/path/config` will use `/some/path/config` as the file. It's also a good idea to have some default settings that you can fall back to if there is no valid config file anywhere.

Comment: Root is also required, by default, to place files in /usr/bin. Since he said his application is there, this implies /etc is accessible to his installer as well.

Answer (score 0):

The config file can go anywhere, but I'd try to put it in the same directory as any other files the program will read or write.

As for how the executable will find it, I'd pass the config file's path to the executable on the command line as an argument, with a default value of "." (which is the current directory, the one you're in when you launch the executable).

Comment: but the config file is always required, and I'd like to avoid having to pass it as an argument every time. can I place them in /etc/myprogram/? I wasn't sure what the standard way to do this is.

Comment: @everitt: The answer says the default path is "`.`", which implies you _don't_ have to pass it as an argument every time.

Comment: @everitt: The standard way would be to place them in /etc/myprogram.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: A default path of "." is not always the best idea because it depends on the current working directory when the application is started. If he's putting the program in /usr/bin that implies he wants to run it from any location on the command line, meaning the config file would have to be in whatever directory the user starts it from -- likely undesired behavior. This also has to be considered when, e.g., starting from a .desktop link, care must be taken to set the startup directory to the installed file location. Better to put it in a known absolute path with an option to override.

Comment: @Beta: Linux provides a /etc directory specifically for this purpose.